# Swapping the contents of two text files

Tags: batch-file

I am working with a batch file and I have these two txt files named
`a.txt` which contains "hello" and `b.txt` which contains "hi".

How can I swap the contents of the two txt files such that `a.txt` contains "hi" and `b.txt` contains "hello"?

Answer (score 2):

```
@echo off
ren a.txt c.txt
ren b.txt a.txt
ren c.txt b.txt
```

**EDIT**:

```
@echo off
ren %1.txt tempfile
ren %2.txt %1.txt
ren tempfile %2.txt
```

Save it as `swap.bat` and use it like:

```
swap a.txt b.txt
```

Comment: is there any other possible solution without using ren? because in my case its not just 2 files to be swapped, and it will cost a lot of line to rename all those files

Comment: If you fail to give accurate details then you will often get solutions that don't work for what you actually want to do.